# How to format output date in Itemwriter?

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-batch

I've a domain class as follows

```
class SubScritpion{

 private String subScripId;
 private String useId;
 private  Date subScripDate;
 private Date billStartDate;
 private Date billEndDate;
 private  int amount;

 //getters and Setters
}
```

And I'm reading this data from database with data type as timestamp in database and converting it to java.util.Date  and writing to csv file using `flatefileItemwriter`, my ItemWriter is as follows.

```
<bean id="kpCvsFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
        scope="step">
        <!-- write to this csv file -->
        <property name="resource" value="file:/#{jobParameters['abs.file.path']}" />
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value="," />

                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names"
                            value="subScripId,useId,subScripDate,billStartDate,billEndDate,amount" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="headerCallback" ref="kpFileHeader" />

    </bean>
```

Now the problem is the date format my database has the date format `17-NOV-14 04.25.06.806000000 AM` but the csv file contains the date format `Mon Nov 17 04:25:06 UTC 2014`.

I did not find any formmatter which can be pluged into ItemWriter though I find some reference for  ItemReader.

One way is to fix this issue by introducing ItemProcesser and convert the the date format to String with SimpleDateFormatter and write to new field in the domain ojbect with and then refer this new fields instead of the Date filed in itemWriter.

But I would like to have cleaner solution something similar to `CustomEditor` that can be applied value-type in spring xml. Could somebody point out some resource in this regard or direction

Comment: Could you guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574629/java-util-illegalformatconversionexception-a-java-lang-string-in-spring-batc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Formatter" that you're looking for is the `LineAggregator`.  Currently you're using the `DelimitedLineAggregator`, which while addressing the delimited aspect of your data, doesn't address formatting.  Take a look at the `FormatterLineAggregator`.  It allows you to format the output `String` generated from the `LineAggregator` by specifying a string format (uses `String.format()`).  From there you should be able to specify the format you want the date to be rendered in.

Comment: That does not solve my problem FormatterLineAggreator does not solve the problem. I've created formatter as follows. %1$td-%1$Tb-%1$ty %1$tI.%1$tM.%1$tS.%1$tN %1$Tp,%2$d. however since fieldextractor passes empty instead of null  %2$d fails.

Comment: There are two phases to the extraction of data into a line.  The first is the extraction of the fields from the item via the `FieldExtractor`.  If you need nulls instead of empty strings, create a custom `FieldExtractor` implementation.  The second phase is formatting those fields into the desired output.  Your question was about the second phase in which the `FormatterLineAggergator` can work if you provide the correct data from the first phase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input!1 I was thinking for the custom fieldEtractor. But as you are PL of SB, I wanted to ask you a question, don't you think there should be niece way to handle formating especially for date(java has so many mess-up with date, and now again new date api with java 8)? Though I would prefer to play around with simpledateformat

Comment: There's nothing from stopping you from creating your own `LineAggregator` instead and putting your own formatting logic in it.  I guess we could add a way to register custom transformers by type, but that may be a bit complex for something so simple...

Comment: @Michael Minella - Could you please share the code snippet? As you are originator of Spring Batch, so we expect always code snippet. Pls do the needful.